# Has the Master Ball failed at any point in the Pokemon anime?

Tags: pokemon

I am huge fan of Pokémon games but I haven't watched the anime that much. As lots of guys here know that Master ball is the ball which catches Pokémon without failing. Today I ran into an argument with a friend of mine regarding the Master ball. He said that the Master ball had failed one time in the anime, but I disagreed that it can never happen. But he said that he had watched it once but can't recall now. Had the Master ball really failed or not?

Comment: You should note that the mechanics of the games are generally consistent whereas the anime treats the mechanics as subservient to the plot.

The fact that the games work a certain way is never going to be a winning argument about anything in the anime.

Comment: Also the master ball will fail **in the games** if you try to catch a pokémon that is owned by another trainer

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In **Episode 35**, titled *Whiscash and Ash*, Season 7 of the Pokemon series, a Whiscash swallows a Master ball thrown at it. This was widely interpreted as a Master ball fail.

[image]

Episode summary:  [**Whiscash and Ash**](http://pokemon.wikia.com/wiki/AG075:_Whiscash_and_Ash)

Comment: Oh that's why its success is written 99.6% due to this failure. I don't get about which Pokemon season. what is season 7 's name?

Comment: Season 7 of the Pokémon anime: [Advanced Challenge](http://pokemon.wikia.com/wiki/Pokémon:_Advanced_Challenge)

Comment: Well, had the ball been thrown correctly and the execution was fair, the Whiscash *can* be caught with ease. So it wasn't a fail by the Master ball, but rather a good counter by the Whiscash. I mean, come on, you can catch legendaries with that thing xD